# Using ngx-toastr with socket.io in Angular 2 application

Tags: javascript, angular, socket.io

I have an Angular 2 application with socket.io. Here's how the socket.io.ts file looks like:

```
import * as defSocketIO from 'socket.io-client';

export class SocketIO {

public static bootstrap(options : object) : SocketIO {
    return new SocketIO(options);
}

constructor(options: Object) {

    (<any> window).SocketIO = new defSocketIO(
        location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port == '' ? '' : ':' + location.port),
        {
            'reconnection'          : false,
            'reconnectionAttempts'  : 0,
            'reconnectionDelay'     : 100000,
            'timeout'               : 900000
        }
    );

    (<any> window).SocketIO.on('connect',  function () {
            console.log("Connected to Socket.io server...");
        }
    );

    (<any> window).SocketIO.on('disconnect',  function () {
            console.log("Disconnected to Socket.io server...");
        }
    );
```

However in the application I'm using `ngx-toastr`, and It's working fine in components, but I would like to use it for socket messages. I've tried to import it several ways, but I can't get it work. Am I able to inject it somehow? 
[Here](https://github.com/scttcper/ngx-toastr) is ngx-toastr

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this by creating an own service from Toastr and imported that in socket.io.ts file.